# Мулькурсор в PHPStorm (аналог из VSCode) | Hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm, hotkeys

В **VSCode** команда **Command + D** (macOS) выполняет действие добавления следующего вхождения текущего выделенного текста *(Add Selection to Next Find Match)*. Эта команда особенно полезна, когда вы хотите быстро **по одному** выделить все вхождения определенного фрагмента текста в вашем документе

Как сделать аналогичный хоткей в PHPStorm без использования мыши?

Comment: Поиск (`Ctrl+F`): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqquw.png

Comment: @RomanGrinyov
Это просто поиск, мне нужен именно мультикурсор.

Иными словами я хочу делать вот такие штуки, но не в VSCode, а в PHPStorm - https://disk.yandex.ru/i/ezqB7zMCeNemTw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ самостоятельно.
Для MacOS используется команда **Control + G**

Comment: `Alt+J` для Linux. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html#multiple_words